# Select selected items in Twig in the select option

Tags: php, twig

I have this code:

```
{% set selectedIdItems = "{{ pageTemplate.pageHeader.pageValue.comp1X }}"|split('|') %}


<select name="comp1" id="comp1" multiple>
<option value=""></option>
 {% for dataValue in pageTemplate.pageHeader.pageValue.categoryArray %}
   <option value="{{ dataValue.id }}">{{ dataValue.name }}</option>
 {% endfor %}
</select>
```

selectedIdItems has values in original form (before split): |1|2|3

in array "selectedIdItems" I have selected options.

How can I set this in select ?
(i want add: selected="selected" in my options)

How can I make it?

**UPDATE**

I trying this code, but it's not working (don't add selected):

```
<select name="comp1" id="comp1" multiple>
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        {% for dataValue in pageTemplate.pageHeader.pageValue.categoryArray %}
                                            <option {% if dataValue.id in selectedIdItems %} selected="selected" {% endif %} value="{{ dataValue.id }}">{{ dataValue.name }}</option>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </select>
```

Comment: Sounds like you want the [in](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#containment-operator) operator.

Comment: I try this: <select name="comp1" id="comp1" multiple>
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        {% for dataValue in pageTemplate.pageHeader.pageValue.categoryArray %}
                                            <option {% if dataValue.id in pickElm1 %} selected="selected" {% endif %} value="{{ dataValue.id }}">{{ dataValue.name }}</option>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </select> - but it's not working

Comment: Please put relevant code in your question, not in comments.  Also, "not working" doesn't tell us much.  Say what _is_ happening, and how it differs from what you want.

Comment: ok, I add my code to post

Comment: What is `pickElm1`?  You're defining your array as `selectedIdItems`

Comment: i change my post

Answer (score 0):

As you are already inside a `twig` statement you don't need to use `{{ ... }}`.
That is used to output stuff.

```
{% set selectedIdItems = "{{ pageTemplate.pageHeader.pageValue.comp1X }}"|split('|') %}
```

Also, by using the snippet above, your variable `selectedItItems` will hold the literal string `{{ pageTemplate.pageHeader.pageValue.comp1X }}`, as variables don't get interpolated between quotes in `twig`

Change your code to

```
{% set selectedIdItems = pageTemplate.pageHeader.pageValue.comp1X|split('|') %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/er5fol)